# Como puedo relacionar tablas en Laravel con llaves foraneas?

Tags: laravel

[image: BASE PLANILLA]

Ya lo relacione con esto:

```
public function up()
{

    Schema::create('personal', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id_personal');
        $table->string('paterno',50);
        $table->string('materno',50);
        $table->string('nombre',50);
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_categoria');
        $table->foreign('id_categoria')->references('id_categoria')->on('categoria')
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Pero quiero relacionar las tres tablas tambíen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que el orden de tus migraciones debería quedar del modo siguiente

**categoria**

Generas la migración con el siguiente comando

```
php artisan make:migration create_categoria_table
```

---

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('categoria', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id_categoria');
        $table->decimal('costo_hora', 10, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**personal**

Generas la migración con el siguiente comando

```
php artisan make:migration create_personal_table
```

---

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('personal', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id_personal');
        $table->string('paterno',50);
        $table->string('materno',50);
        $table->string('nombre',50);
        $table->unsignedInteger('categoria_id');
        $table->foreign('categoria_id')->references('id_categoria')->on('categoria')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**sueldo**

Generas la migración con el siguiente comando

```
php artisan make:migration create_sueldo_table
```

---

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('sueldo', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id_sueldo');
        $table->decimal('horas', 10, 2);
        $table->decimal('importe', 10, 2);
        $table->string('periodo');
        $table->unsignedInteger('personal_id');
        $table->foreign('personal_id')->references('id_personal')->on('personal')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**ACLARACIONES**

> 1. Las migraciones van una por archivo
> 2. La tabla de categoria va primero, pues no depende de nunguna otra para existir
> 3. personal va despues por que depende en su estructura de categoria
> 4. Sueldo va al final por que su existencia misma, depende de personal y a su vez personal depende de categoria

**OBSERVACIONES**

Las llaves foráneas, trata de nombrarlas del siguiente modo

```
nombreColumna_id

user_id
```

***además en singular***

Comment: En tu respuesta te faltó agregar el engine de las tablas que vayan a utilizar llave foránea: `$tabla->engine = 'InnoDB';`, además yo le agregaría un `->onDelete('cascade')` a las llaves foráneas para mantener la integridad de datos

Comment: respecto al engine, si lo omites Laravel lo asume por defecto y usa InnoDB respecto a lo segundo tienes razón y lo colocaré @AarónGutiérrez

Comment: ¿si?, ¿tienes la referencia de donde dice que asume `InnoDB`?, no me he percatado pero al menos de la versión 5.4 para abajo me marcaba error porque asumía `MyISAM` y ahora ya se me hizo un hábito siempre establecer el engine.

Comment: trabajo con Laravel desde hace tiempo y la práctica me hace indicarte lo que te digo @AarónGutiérrez

Comment: Si, el hecho de tener "tiempo" trabajando con algo no significa convertirse automáticamente en perfecto... ya investigué y el engine por defecto que te pone siempre ha sido `MyISAM`, el engine por defecto cambia si se le especifica en el archivo `config/database.php`, en el atributo 'engine' de tu conexión mysql que estés usando: `'engine' => 'InnoDB'`. No dejes que los puntos de reputación te engañen ;)

Comment: Aquí nadie dijo ser perfecto, mencioné que llevo tiempo usandolo y siempre he trabajado de ese modo; en la comunidad esperamos apoyo no comentarios burlones y mucho menos si vienes a atacar sin razón @AarónGutiérrez

Comment: Fue un error de dedo, ya lo quité, pero bueno, yo no vine a pelear, pero si defiendo lo que digo cuando tengo bases, no es una buena justificación decir “he trabajado con x framework mucho tiempo y eso me hace tener la razón en esto”, y bueno ya, no es un foro para discutir.

Comment: Disculpe una vez relacionada las tablas entre ellas con "foreign", puedo visualizar en modo diseñador en phpmyadmin las tablas relacionadas? Seria mucha ayuda que me ayuden en eso y si me pueden ayudarn en un pequeño trabajo que me han dejado en la univ, muchas gracias

Comment: @Alfredo Paz puse la migracion que me pusiste y me sale un error al momento de ejecutar la migracion

Comment: @Carlos que error te salió?, por favor no aceptes la respuesta hasta que el error se corrija y te sea funcional agradezco la desmarques

Comment: General error:1005 Can't create table 'planilla' : #sql-b68-10e'
error : "Foreing key constraint is incorrectly formed" Es más lo que sale pero eso es lo que puse

Comment: @Carlos si te das cuenta en mi respuesta no creo ninguna tabla llamada planilla, quiere decir que tienes otra migración también ejecutandose para crear una tabla con ese nombre pero esta mal estructurada; se te puede apoyar pero entonces añade la info de esa tabla en tu pregunta original

Comment: no es tabla "planilla" sino es la bd "planilla" pero asi me sale el error en el comando = "php artisan migrate"